# Why, in Ruby, does Array("foo\nbar") == ["foo\n", "bar"]?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

In Ruby 1.8.7, `Array("hello\nhello")` gives you `["hello\n", "hello"]`. This does two things that I don't expect:

1. It splits the string on newlines. I'd expect it simply to give me an array with the string I pass in as its single element without modifying the data I pass in.
2. Even if you accept that it's reasonable to split a string when passing it to Array, why does it retain the newline character when `"foo\nbar".split` does not?

Additionally:

```
>> Array.[] "foo\nbar"
=> ["foo\nbar"]
>> Array.[] *"foo\nbar"
=> ["foo\n", "bar"]
```

Comment: FWIW, this is no longer true in Ruby 1.9.1. No splitting is done at all.

Comment: Yay for backwards compatibility :) (Although Ruby's policy might be to break it on minor version number changes, as opposed to major. Again, any convention is good as any other and better than none at all.)

Comment: I'd guess this is so you can write `Array(File.read(filename))` and it would give you an array of (unchomped) lines as you'd expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It splits the string on newlines. I'd expect it simply to give me an array with the string I pass in as its single element without modifying the data I pass in.

That's a convention as good as any other. For example, the `list` constructor in Python does something entirely different:

```
>>> list("foo")
['f', 'o', 'o']
```

So long as it's consistent I don't see the problem.

> Even if you accept that it's reasonable to split a string when passing it to Array, why does it retain the newline character when `"foo\nbar".split` does not?

My wild guess here (supported by quick googling and [TryRuby](http://tryruby.org/)) is that the `.split` method for strings does so to make it the "inverse" operation of the `.join` method for arrays.

```
>> "foospambar".split("spam").join("spam")
=> "foospambar"
```

---

By the way, I cannot replicate your behaviour on [TryRuby](http://tryruby.org/):

```
>> x = Array("foo\nbar")                                                         
=> ["foo\nbar"]   
>> Array.[] *"foo\nbar"                                                 
=> ["foo\nbar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the double-quotes with single-quotes it works as expected:

```
>> Array.[] "foo\nbar"
=> ["foo\nbar"]
>> Array.[] 'foo\nbar'
=> ["foo\\nbar"]
```

Comment: No, actually, that means the newline is not interpreted at all.

Comment: Which is what Tyson wanted, though it doesn't answer the why.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
"foo\nbar".split(/w/)
"foo\nbar".split(/^/)
"foo\nbar".split(/$/)
```

and other regular expressions.